# PHP convert a Byte Array to a Float value

Tags: php

I am reading values over a (modbusTCP) connection. I get back an array with the following data:

```
print_r($recData) ;
Output: Array ( [0] => 67 [1] => 100 [2] => 33 [3] => 72 )
```

how do I get the values back as float? as result I should get the following:
229.718

my code dosent work... the data in $recData shout be a Float Big Endian Value

```
$i = ($recData[0]<<24) + ($recData[1]<<16) + ($recData[2]<<8) + ($recData[3]);
```

Comment: _I should get the following: 229.718_ Where is this value initially?

Comment: The values are from a Modbus register.
When I look at the display of the device it says 229.718 (volts).
Read out via Modbus I get the array with the 4 values 67 100 33 72

Comment: `0x4365b7cf` is the hex representation of the IEEE-754 Floating Point encoding of your number, https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may convert it inside PHP like that.

```
$number = [67, 100, 33, 72];
$strHex = implode('', array_map('dechex', $number));

$v = hexdec($strHex);
$x = ($v & ((1 << 23) - 1)) + (1 << 23) * ($v >> 31 | 1);
$exp = ($v >> 23 & 0xFF) - 127;
$float = $x * pow(2, $exp - 23);

echo round($float, 3);
```

gives

```
228.13
```